# What's wrong "syntax error near unexpected token `fi'"?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, ubuntu-20.04

I can't deal with the problem. I run the script (I'll attach it below), after the first question I get the error "line 37 syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
If fi is removed, nothing changes.
Help me to understand...
I tried many solutions, and dos2unix configuration, and double-checked all the indents

```
#!/bin/bash
function pause (){
  read -p "Press any key to continue ... "
}
timedatectl set-timezone Atlantic/Reykjavik
a=`date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"`
echo -n -e "Current Date/Time is    " 
date
sleep 2
read -p "is it correct (Yes/No) ? " CC
  if [ "$CC" == "N" -o "$CC" == "n" ];then 
    echo "Exit testing ..."
    exit
  fi 
else
  read -p "Do you want to change (Yes/No) ? " CC
  if [ "$CC" == "Y" -o "$CC" == "y" ];then
    read -p "Please input new date, format: YYYYMMDD  " D
    NEWD="`echo $D | cut -b 1-4`"-"`echo $D | cut -b 5-6`"-"`echo $D | cut -b 7-8`"    
    read -p "Please input new time, format: HHMM   " T
    NEWT="`echo $T | cut -b 1-2`":"`echo $T | cut -b 3-4`":"00"    
    echo -n "date -s '" > d.sh
    echo -n "$NEWD $NEWT" >> d.sh
    echo "'" >> d.sh
    chmod 777 d.sh
    ./d.sh
    echo
    sleep 1
    clock -w
    sleep 1
    a=`date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"`
    echo -n -e "NEW Date/Time is""\e[0;32m $a\e[0m"", "
    read -p "Press ENTER to continue..."
  fi
```

UPD: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQ4j4.png)
Display after deletion "else"

**UPD2** ***This is second similar code that gives the same error. Plus, doesn't request the entry of information ("Please input the First MAC address:)***

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSxbF.png)

```
echo "************************"
echo "  Serial number setting "
echo "************************"

SLEN=0
while [ "$SLEN" != "13" ]
do 
read -p "Please input Serial Number:" sn
SLEN="${#sn}"
done

echo "*************************"
echo "   MAC-address setting   "
echo "*************************"

PLEN=0
until [ "$PLEN" == "12" ] && [ "$VID" == "0015B2" ]
do 
  read -p "Please input the First MAC address: " MACIN
  PLEN="${#MACIN}"
  if [ $PLEN != 12 ];then 
    echo
    echo MAC address LENTH error !!
  fi
  MAC=`echo $MACIN | tr a-z A-Z`
  VID=`echo $MAC | cut -b 1-6`
  if [ "$VID" != "0015B2" ];then
    echo
    echo -n "The first 6 digit MUST be"
    echo -n -e "\e[0;37;42m 0015B2 \e[0m", but you input 
    echo -e "\e[0;37;41m $VID \e[0m""!!" 
  fi
done
```

Comment: The code you posted is only 34 lines, there is no line 36.

Comment: It seems like there are extra lines after this, and that's where the erroneous `fi` is.

Comment: There are information lines that i don't specify the beginning at the beginning (echo "******time setting*******" read -p " Press Enter to continue...") @Barmar

Comment: Post your exact script, maybe those lines are relevant to the problem.

Comment: First paste your script into shellcheck.net and fix all the problems it finds.

Comment: я добавила второй аналогичны скрипт имеющий такую же ошибку. (смотри УПД 2) , в shellcheck - ОК @Barmar

Comment: I'm not sure why it would cause this error, but check your file for carriage return characters, and fix it with `dos2unix`.

Comment: Remove fi before else and try now.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely explanation for your problem is an 'exotic' (non-ASCII) Unicode character within your script.
Like most scripting and programming languages, Bash cannot stand the presence of non-ASCII characters within or next to a token.

For example, there is a space following `then` in this statement:

```
if [ "$CC" == "N" -o "$CC" == "n" ];then
```

This is fine, as long as that space is the ASCII space character (U+0020).
**If** that space character would happen to be a non-breaking space (U+00A0),
then you will get *exactly* the error that you witnessed:

```
Current Date/Time is    Thu Jul 21 16:39:09 WEDT 2022
is it correct (Yes/No) ? y
./test.sh: line 14: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
./test.sh: line 14: `  fi '
```

That was just an example. There are many more Unicode characters that can cause this problem.

- Zero-width space (U+200B) next to or even *within* a token. As the name suggests, this character is invisible in most fonts.
- Non-ASCII letters; I remember a similar problem caused by a Cyrillic Es taking the place of a roman C in an identifier. In many fonts, the two are indistinguishable.

I strongly advice you to take a hex viewer and *very carefully* inspect your script for the presence of Unicode characters.

Answer (score 0):

Remove "else" after the first if block and your code should work

Comment: It didn't work.. Gives the same error in the last line. Even without "else"

Comment: Check your code here -> https://www.shellcheck.net/